# ARKit on iPhone 5s

Tags: xcode, arkit

I im trying to use ARKit on my iPhone 5s, but when I build and run I get this message:

"This iPhone 5s (Model A1457, A1518, A1528, A1530) is running iOS 11.3 (15E216), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode."

I have other projects that I build and run with no problem on the device, but for some reason it won't when I include ARKit.

Answer (score 3):

**Devices Supported by ARKit.**

ARKit is supported on devices with A9 or later processor which includes:

- iPhone 6s and later
- iPhone SE
- Any iPad Pro
- iPad 2017 and later

**Why Use ARKit?**

Although there is a limitation on devices, why use ARKit?

- ARKit detects horizontal plane, vertical plane (with ARKit 1.5 and iOS 11.3 onwards).
- It uses phone's camera and its motion coprocessors like M10 chips which can effectively track data from the gyroscope, accelerometer, and magnetometer to track movement as iPhone is moved and tilted. This lets it monitor movement in a 3D space without needing for sophisticated hardware.
- More importantly, ARKit is officially supported, part of the platform, require no external libs, and has Cocoa level documentation. In addition, Apple could afford to do the work to tightly couple the VIO(Visual Inertial Odometry) algorithm to the sensors and spend a lot of time calibrating them to eliminate errors.

**Other AR third party Frameworks:**

If you have the necessity to support most of the iOS devices. You can go for these third-party frameworks.

- [Vuforia](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Getting-Started-with-Vuforia-for-iOS-Development) (popular and supports above iOS 6, they have support for both iOS and android)
- [EasyAR](https://www.easyar.com/)
- [AR-media](http://www.armedia.it/)

are few to mention.

Answer (score 2):

From the [ARKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/):

> ARKit requires an iOS device with an A9 or later processor.

Your iPhone 5s has an A7 processor, which does not support ARKit.

Comment: Are there any frameworks I could use, so I dont lose all people with iPhone 5s?

Comment: @Lasee, No, it doesn't work that way.
It's a definite hardware requirement that Apple has set.

Answer (score 2):

ARKit is not supported on iphone 5s but you can develop AR projects using [AR.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js)
which enables AR on Web. You can insert a [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/) in your app and use AR.js inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Xcode 9 or later which support ARKit
All devices having A9 processor (or newer) support ARKit